# Removing last instance of duplicates

Tags: python, list

Removing duplicates from a list in Python is easy (order preserving):

```
def removeDuplicates(sequence):    
    checked = []
    for element in sequence:
        if element not in checked:
            checked.append(element)
    return checked
```

But if I want to remove remove the last instance of the duplicates (ie: `[1,1,1,2,2,2] -> [1,1,2,2]`), how can I do it?

Comment: Is it really "generalization"?

Comment: If they're duplicates, why does it matter?

Comment: @HenryKeiter I've made the assumption in my answer that the objects being deduped are a bit more complex than just numbers and that only one item per key is required but they're multiple objects with the same key, but varying other attributes

Comment: It was just a list with numbers to give a general idea but I think Jon's answer is the nearest from a use in real world coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - Traverse the list, and add each element into a dictionary, let's call it `duplicateMap`.**

```
Key: element in the list

Value: count of element
```

**2 - Traverse the list again from the back.**

For each element, check

```
1) if duplicateMap contains the element;
2) if the count is greater than 1.
```

If yes,

```
1) remove the element from the list;
2) remove the element from duplicateMap.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

data = [
    ['Jim', 18],
    ['James', 19],
    ['Bob', 20],
    ['Jim', 15],
    ['Bob', 55],
    ['Jim', 99],
    ['Single', 123]
]

od = OrderedDict()
for el in data:
    od.setdefault(el[0], []).append(el)

deduped = list(chain.from_iterable(item[:-1] if len(item) > 1 else item for item in od.itervalues()))
# [['Jim', 18], ['Jim', 15], ['James', 19], ['Bob', 20], ['Single', 123]]
```

This uses names and ages as example data and dedupes based on the name - which is a bit more interesting than just numbers... We append them to a list each and at the end take all the elements and put them back into order of presented keys grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

My python isn't too great but how about this:

```
>>> l = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
>>> last_occ=[len(l) - 1 - l[::-1].index(i) for i in set(l)] # Find position of each last occurence
>>> for pos in last_occ[::-1]: # Reverse the occurrence list otherwise you may get an IndexError 
    l.pop(pos)
>>> l
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

How About like this

```
def removelastduplicate(s):
  len_s=len(s)
  checked=[]
  for i in range(0,len_s):
    number=s.pop(0)
    if number in s: # the last occurance wont be present in the list, so not added
      checked.append(number)
  return checked

s=[1,1,1,2,2,2]
print removelastduplicate(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mind is in Javascript mode right now, so the code isn't coming to me off the top of my head, but conceptually, the idea that first comes to my mind is:

```
for x in originalList  of [A,A,B,B,A,B,C,C]
store x as entry in dictionary {A:[0,1,4];B:[2,3,5];C:[6,7]}
Then loop through all of the lists in the dictionary and pull the max value
    from each and push it to a new list that you then reverse sort, 
    ex output [7,5,4]
Then for each value in the resulting list, remove the value at that place in the original list
    (Do it in the largest to least order though, that way as you remove values, its not changing the value of the other entries that need to be removed)
```

There's probably a better way to do this, and I'm sorry I don't have the code for you off hand for that idea, but I hope the concept helps,  if you need me to further explain what I mean, just let me know.